# Best Test for deciding if two variables are correlated

Tags: t-test, statsmodels

Novice in stats.

I need to determine if the specific activity (SA) is correlated with protein purity recieved via SDS-PAGE across a multi column purification procedure.

My current plan is to normalize the data by dividing by the lowest values for each set, then run a paired T-Test and only accepting values above .95.

Is there a better test to run though?

here is the data

SA

[image: SA]

vs

purity

[image]

Is there a better test to run?

Comment: If you're interested in correlation, why would you propose a test which examines differences in means?  Additionally, are these your only data?  Four data points is woefully small.

Comment: It is for a class. And that is my issue, I know that T-test is for differences, but I never learned a test to decide if something is the same.